# Python Is it possible to call a pickfile window with pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, pygame

[EDIT] This question is not awnsered because I searching a better alternative to ot use tkinter with invisible window

I would my program open a file picker window. It's a pygame project, and I haven't found a way to call file picker window under it.

I tried to use a function of tkintker

```py
from tkinter import filedialog
path=filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

But a horrible Tkinter appear and and not removable else you close the program.

So is a way to do it simple ?

I would it's return me the `path` in `path` variable

Comment: Please add a plain python tag

Comment: ok I'll to it :D